# Maya Python API Scaling a matrix about another matrix

Tags: python, api, matrix, maya

So I have two matrices in maya. I want to reflect one matrix about the x and y of that other matrix.

So as an example:

Object 1's matrix is as such:
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.70710678118654746, 0.70710678118654757, 0.0, 0.0, -0.70710678118654757, 0.70710678118654746, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
This is an object at the origin rotated 45 degrees along the x.

Object 2's matrix is as such:
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]
Sitting at 2,2,2 in worldspace with no rotation values.

When reflected on scaleX of object1 we get a matrix like this:
[1.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.70710678118654746, -0.70710678118654757, 0.0, 0.0, 0.70710678118654757, 0.70710678118654746, 0.0, 2.0, 2.8284271247461898, -2.2204460492503131e-16, 1.0]

This is just me querying matrices when I'm manually reflecting the object's scale. What would the method be for doing this in python API?

I'm assuming some way with MTransformationMatrix but aren't able to figure that one out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you'd create a MMatrix or MTransformationMatrix in the API and multiply them together in series to get the transformation you want. The hassle is getting the values from Python into those classes, which requires the dreaded [MScriptUtil](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_script_util.html)

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import maya.cds as cmds


def APIMatrix ( valList ):  # where vallist is a list of floats
    mat = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
    OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.createMatrixFromList( valList, mat )
    return mat
```

Would create an MMatrix from a list of python numbers, for example. In Pymel things are easier using the [Matrix](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/generated/classes/pymel.core.datatypes/pymel.core.datatypes.Matrix.html) class:

```
import pymel.datatypes as dt

i = dt.Matrix() # creates an identity matrix
m = dt.Matrix ( list_of_values) # use supplied numbers
```

Once you've multiplied your matrices you can apply them with the xform command:

```
cmds.xform(item, m = my_new_matrix)
```

or in pymel:

```
import pymel.core as pm
pm.xform(item, my_new_pymel_matrix)
```

MMatrix is a raw matrix - just numbers for doing math [MTransformationMatrix](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_transformation_matrix.html) is more like the actual transform of an object : it offers methods for, eg, poking numbers into the translation or rotation without knowing which matrix members to twiddle by hand:

```
def get_obj_quaternion ( mayaTransform, worldSpace=True ):
    '''
    gets the rotation quat for the supplied dag node in world or local space
    '''
    #convert from mMatrix to MTransformationMatrix....
    mMatrix = matrix_from_transform( mayaTransform, worldSpace=worldSpace )
    mTransformMtx = OpenMaya.MTransformationMatrix( mMatrix )

    # MscriptUtil. Sigh
    xPtr = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil(0.0)
    x = xPtr.asDoublePtr()

    yPtr = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil(0.0)
    y = yPtr.asDoublePtr()

    zPtr = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil(0.0)
    z = zPtr.asDoublePtr()

    wPtr = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil(0.0)
    w = wPtr.asDoublePtr()

    mTransformMtx.getRotationQuaternion( x, y, z, w )
    # getRotationQuaternion is an MTransformationMatrix method

    #convert them back to normal python floats
    x = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil().getDouble( x )
    y = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil().getDouble( y )
    z = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil().getDouble( z )
    w = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil().getDouble( w )

    return x, y, z, w
```

So in your case you'd want to :

**1)** get the matrix of your target object

**2)** get the matrix of your reflection object

**3)** make a reflection matrix, for example :

```
 -1  0  0  0
  0  1  0  0 
  0  0 -1  0
  0  0  0  1
```

is the reflection matrix for reflecting the X and Z axes

**4)** Reflect target as:

```
reflected_matrix = reflectXZMatrix * reflectionObjectMatrix
result = target_matrix * reflected_matrix
cmds.xform( target_object, m = result)
```

This is a minimalist version using only MMatrices - if you needed to construct the matrix yourself, an MTransformationMatrix would let you set up a rotation or scale matrix without manually managing the numbers in the matrices.

Comment: Sounds good I'll give it a go and get back to you. Thanks for the response. I'm already constructing the matrix by hand but this makes sense for reflecting it.

Comment: If you haven't done this before you should check out the docs for Transform (http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Nodes/transform.html) which layout the transform order (maya uses post multiply : transforms go in left to right order as in my example above)

Comment: So I'm noticing an issue actually. When reflecting on say a sphere that's rotated using my code, it won't reflect the matrix properly. Ideas? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: I've been assume the 'reflection' you wanted it similar to maya's mirror joint. There's also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix (look at the 3d section - it describes the top-left 3 x 3 of the 4 x 4 matrix...

Comment: It's the same idea as maya's mirror joint. I have a feeling my reflection matrix is just incorrect to what I want.

Comment: You could just make a joint, mirror, and copy its matrix over the same way :)

Comment: I also could parent an object and set it's scale to -1 on X and Z, but I'd like to know how to do it with matrices. Since it's also for a quick plugin idea i'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer contains an incorrect example. **Never** write something such as `ptr = OpenMaya.MScriptUtil().asDoublePtr()`. For an explanation why, read the second point there: http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2013/03/possible-misuse-of-mscriptutil-in-maya.html.

Also, the same example is helpful in showing how to use the class `MScriptUtil` but, for this specific method, here is a version that is both more convenient to write and faster to run:

```
def get_obj_quaternion ( mayaTransform, worldSpace=True ):
    '''
    gets the rotation quat for the supplied dag node in world or local space
    '''
    #convert from mMatrix to MTransformationMatrix....
    mMatrix = matrix_from_transform( mayaTransform, worldSpace=worldSpace )
    mTransformMtx = OpenMaya.MTransformationMatrix( mMatrix )
    q = mTransformMtx.rotation()
    return [q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w]
```

Comment: I am not a reputation chaser, and even though I am not answering the question here, I wished that this answer was upvoted to prevent people from blindly copy/pasting the code shown in the example. I tried to edit the original answer but for some reasons the edit was rejected...

Comment: I've edited the answer to fix the problem (it will have to be peer reviewed). I ended up going with the answer I posted so I didn't run into this specific issue. I don't see what your version of the method is doing different than the posted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Woops, my bad, I didn't write the full function in the example, it's fixed now. It's not the most critical point anyways—I'm mostly concerned with seeing the pattern `OpenMaya.MScriptUtil().asDoublePtr()` being used all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I got to work with the idea you gave me. Makes so much sense now!

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import maya.cmds as cmds
import math

reflectObj = cmds.xform('pSphere1', query=True, ws=True, matrix=True)
targetObj = cmds.xform('pSphere2', query=True, ws=True, matrix=True)
reflectXZ = [-1 * reflectObj[0], -1 * reflectObj[1], -1 * reflectObj[2], reflectObj[3],
             -1 * reflectObj[4], -1 * reflectObj[5], -1 * reflectObj[6], reflectObj[7],
             reflectObj[8], reflectObj[9], reflectObj[10], reflectObj[11],
             reflectObj[12], reflectObj[13], reflectObj[14], reflectObj[15]]

targetMMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.createMatrixFromList(targetObj, targetMMatrix)

reflectObjMMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.createMatrixFromList(reflectObj, reflectObjMMatrix)

reflectXZMMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
OpenMaya.MScriptUtil.createMatrixFromList(reflectXZ, reflectXZMMatrix)

reflected_matrix = targetMMatrix * reflectObjMMatrix.inverse()
result = reflected_matrix * reflectXZMMatrix

mt = OpenMaya.MTransformationMatrix(result)

trans = mt.translation(OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld)
eulerRot = mt.rotation().asEulerRotation()
angles = [math.degrees(angle) for angle in (eulerRot.x, eulerRot.y, eulerRot.z)]
loc = cmds.spaceLocator()
cmds.move(trans[0], trans[1], trans[2], loc[0])
cmds.rotate(angles[0], angles[1], angles[2], loc[0])
```

In this case I just made two spheres and was able to reflect on those matrices.
Edit: Corrected this to work off any rotation.

Comment: UPDATE:

I ended up getting an answer by doing some vector math.

[Here's the formula for it](http://www.3dkingdoms.com/weekly/weekly.php?a=2)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing it with vectors to get the position. Replace obj1 and obj2 with your reflection object and object to reflect.

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

get_pnt = partial(cmds.xform,
                 query=True,
                 worldSpace=True,
                 translation=True)

N = OpenMaya.MVector(*get_pnt('obj1'))
N.normalize()
V = OpenMaya.MVector(*get_pnt('obj2'))
R = (N * 2.0) * (V * N) - V

loc = cmds.spaceLocator()
cmds.move(R.x, R.y, R.z, loc[0])
```

[Formula for vector reflection](http://www.3dkingdoms.com/weekly/weekly.php?a=2)